# html2canvas not rendering full div

Tags: angularjs, html2canvas, pdfmake

I am using html2canvas along with pdfmake to export as pdf and I can only get the screen visible in current window and I cannot get the full div and the div is having overflow as hidden on it.

```
var target = document.getElementById('centerRow');
target.className += ' html2canvasreset';    
html2canvas(target, {
  preload: function() {
    target.className = angular
      .getElementById('centerRow')
      .removeClass('html2canvasreset');
  },
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
   target.className += 'html2canvasBack';
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var docDefinition = {pageSize: 'A1',content: [{image: data}]};
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('export.pdf');
  }
});
```

};

Comment: share your code here or create plunker for that so we can identify what's the problem in that.

Comment: Here are the css classes used.                                      
  html2canvasreset{
    overflow: visible !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
        }
        .html2canvasBack{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: 100% !important;
        }

Comment: don't use CSS classes apply CSS internally. might be the problem in classes. I have also faced this problem and I solved by applying CSS as inline.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Though I'm trying to get the image and not pdf. I've applied the inline style.